# ViewModel with generic type

Tags: java, android, generics, mvvm

How can i create a `viewModel` with a generic type? Let me show you an example:

**ViewModel**

```
public class MyViewModel<T> extends ViewModel
{
    private Repository<T> repository;

    ...

    @Override
    public LiveData<Model<T>> getModel()
    {
        return repository.getModel();
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
        private MyViewModel<T> viewModel;

        ...

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            // this is where i need my viewModel with the generic type
            viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        }
```

As you can see, i am unable to get the sepecified viewModel i initialized as a variable in my fragment Maybe someone can lead me in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: Generics are only used for compile time safety, then they are erased (they don't exist at runtime). You need to create explicit class for each type and use some kind of factory to select between them.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question asked a long time ago but for anyone else who has same problem you should use a factory class to send your own constructor to a view model class ( in Kotlin Code):

```
//Your view model
class BaseViewModel<K1, K2> : ViewModel() {
}
```

a factory class that extend ViewModelProvider.Factory:

```
    class BaseViewModelFactory<K1,K2>:ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return BaseViewModel<K1,K2>() as T
    }
}
```

and declare your view model in activity or fragment as below:

```
val viewmodel=ViewModelProvider(this, BaseViewModelFactory<K1, K2>())
            .get(BaseViewModel::class.java) as BaseViewModel<K1, K2>
```